# Java reverse/back reference

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a class instance into a constructor of another class and vise versa. I would like to do this:

```
static Map map = new Map(hero);
static Hero hero = new Hero(map);
```

I'm running this code inside my Game class. How do I go about correctly implementing the above code? Is there a better way to go about it?

**EDIT:**

**I think what I really want is lazy loading, like if map is null then make it; otherwise, don't make it. How do I do this in Java?**

Comment: you could create the hero inside the Map constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I made it so that I'm never creating a World class inside of any other class and that my World class would instantiate other classes if it needs them.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You would probably do it via two-stage initialisation.

e.g.

```
static Map map = new Map();
static Hero hero = new Hero();

map.setHero(hero);
hero.setMap(map);
```

And then add guards to the relevant functions to throw a 'not fully initialised' exception if they are called before *setMap / setHero*

Answer (score 4):

Well, the above syntax would not compile, you'd get a `illegal forward reference` compile error.

What you **can** do is construct two objects, and then set the references e.g.

```
static Map map = new Map();
static Hero hero = new Hero();
// and then ...
map.hero(hero);
hero.map(map);
```

Of course the way you name your setters is up to you, if these would behave like true Java Bean setters, you should probably stick to that naming convention (i.e. `setX()` and `getX()`). If a `Map` \ `Hero` class in not usable before using that setter, then perhaps it's the case for the [Builder Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Another option is to use some dependency injection library that would take care of the above things for you, behind the scenes.

The third option is to use a nested class (if it fits your design), e.g.

```
class Map {
    class Hero { ... }
}
```

This way every Hero has a reference to `Map` available via `Map.this`

HTH,
elmes

Comment: I'm thinking that making the Hero in the Map class, renaming to World now that I'm reading everyone's comments, would be a logical option since every World would have a Hero. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, it really depends on the game you are designing. I'd think it over again, is it really necessary to have a circular reference..? Why does the `World` need to know its `Hero`? Why does a `Hero` need to know its `World`?

Comment: A hero needs to know where he's at in the world and he's apart of the world.

Comment: You can try smt like this http://pastebin.com/psC52nq7 and then simply adjust to changes and your needs. Also, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern this out. I guess the `Hero` doesn't need an entire `World`, perhaps a separate `WorldPosition` instance could be passed to him whenever hero needs it..

Answer (score 3):

what you have is `cyclic/circular dependency`. So you need to initialize objects inside one object only. And the best place to do it is `Constructor` of one object.

```
class Map {
    Hero hero = null;

    public Map() {
        hero = new Hero(this);
    }

    public Hero getHero() {
        return hero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can use the suggestion offered by @logical Chimp. I think cyclic reference/depedency is problematic. it's good you pointed out to him that this is the issue.

Comment: @zaske Moving to setter is always great but if he has do something in constructor specific to other object then there is problem in using setter.

Comment: I think this makes sense because every Map, now I'm calling it World, will have a Hero.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest not using cyclic references. 
You may encounter serialization issues (for example, if you want to send your map over the network and store it in a file. 
What I suggest instead is that you have a unique ID for your MAP and for your Hero objects. 
And you hold for example for Hero a "parentId" to its Map. 
Store the man and the hero objects in some cache (maybe a singleton based on HashMap) that will let you retrieve objects by id, and this way, given a hero you will be able to obtain its map quite easily. 
If you still insist on Cyclic reference, see the answer provided by @logical chimp